# What is the purpose of <!-- --> in html navigation list between LI elements?

Tags: html, css

I saw an interesting navigation list example as below (css omitted),

```html
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">Settings</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

At first glimpse, I thought the `<!--` and `-->` between `<li>` tag might be left by mistake. Author just forgot to clear the comment.

[image]

But when I left them out, the navigation bar didn't look the same. Seems they were added on purpose.

[image]

Since I'm not an expert for HTML, anyone can explain? Is that a common trick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a trick to remove newlines that manifest as space between inline elements.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ol > li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
Without &lt!-- --&gt;
<ol>
  <li>ONE</li>
  <li>TWO</li>
  <li>THREE</li>
</ol>
<br>
With &lt!-- --&gt;
<ol>
  <li>ONE</li><!--
  --><li>TWO</li><!--
  --><li>THREE</li>
</ol>
```

It makes the newline character a comment, so in the end there is nothing between the closing and the next opening tag (`</li><li>`).

Alternatively you could put the opening tag immediately after the closing tag on the previous line.

```
<ol>
  <li>ONE</li><li>
  TWO</li><li>
  THREE</li>
</ol>
```

or use `float: left;`, but that also needs `clear: both;` after it.

But those are old tricks. Nowadays you can just use `display: flex;`.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
ol > li {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>ONE</li>
  <li>TWO</li>
  <li>THREE</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: MVP! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The `<!-- -->` is a html comment.

In this case it basically removes the implicit whitespace between the closing li (`</li>`) and the next opening li (`<li>`).

This prevents the spacing you see when you remove it as it makes the elements physically adjacent with no whitespace (everything in between is ignored comment).

There's a pretty thorough explanation of how whitespace is handled on the Mozilla dev network website in the article [How whitespace is handled by HTML, CSS, and in the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace#spaces_in_between_inline_and_inline-block_elements)

Comment: A good reference to read. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for it and can be removed as they are normally just basic HTML comments. They provide no usefulness to the code

as for the formatting difference, you will need to better style them, that's all.

Comment: How to explain the white space between each button when I deleted the `<!--` and `-->`? I'm quite confused.

Comment: * I am not fully sure, but my guess is that there is enough whitespace between the 2 that just pushes whitespace in between ??? that's my best guess as whitespace in the document matter.

Comment: @shen The whitespace is actually coming from the whitespace in your HTML document.  I assume you want to display those list items as blocks rather than whatever is there now, and the outer `ul` as like flex or something, and then you won't have this problem.

Comment: @Brad I've double-checked my code, there's no space.

Comment: I mean, end of the day it doesn't matter. more so the comments are not needed and should be properly styled as such to keep your page in tact and keep to the standards etc..

Comment: When I put the whole list in one single line `<ul><li><a href="#">Profile</a></li><li><a href="#">Settings</a></li><li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li><li><a href="#">Logout</a></li></ul>`, the problem solved.

Comment: @MysticSeagull Seems my VSCode editor automatically add a space every time when I start a new line. Now I understand these `<!-- -->` is used to prevent editor add some extra `space`, `tab` or `\n` between two `<li>` tag. Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: @shen Newline characters are whitespace characters.